# Adding unique numerics to character strings

Tags: r

I wish to append a numeric onto a character vector, so that each row receives a unique numeric different to the previous, though +1 relative to the previous. Such that `n+1`.

I have tried:

```
test.all$ly_name <- sub("^", 1:nrow(test.all$ly_name), test.all$ly_name )
```

What it looks like:

```
1Prairie_Potholes          
1Prairie_Potholes          
1Prairie_Potholes 
.
.
.
```

expected:

```
Prairie_Potholes1          
Prairie_Potholes2          
Prairie_Potholes3 
.
.
.
```

However, this only assign the first numeric, 1.

reproducible code:

```
c("Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", 
"Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", 
"Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", 
"Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", 
"Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition")
```

Comment: @RonakShah updated, have a look

Comment: Do you want to restart the count for the new value? I guess you were trying `test.all$ly_name <- paste0(test.all$ly_name, 1:nrow(test.all$ly_name))`

Comment: That definitely works better, and what I should have had in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `paste0` and `seq_along`. The `seq_along` function generates a vector of integers the same length as the input vector. The `paste0` function pastes the strings together elementwise with no space between.

```
ly_name <- c("Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", 
             "Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", 
             "Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", 
             "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", 
             "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition")

paste0(ly_name, seq_along(ly_name))

 [1] "Prairie_Potholes1"            "Prairie_Potholes2"            "Prairie_Potholes3"           
 [4] "Prairie_Potholes4"            "Prairie_Potholes5"            "Prairie_Potholes6"           
 [7] "Prairie_Potholes7"            "Prairie_Potholes8"            "Prairie_Potholes9"           
[10] "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition10" "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition11" "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition12"
[13] "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition13" "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition14" "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition15"
```

If you happen to want the numbers to restart at 1 every time there is a new `ly_name`, you can use `group_by` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(ly_name)
df %>%
  group_by(ly_name) %>%
  mutate(ly_name = paste0(ly_name, seq_along(ly_name)))

# A tibble: 15 x 1
# Groups:   ly_name [15]
   ly_name                    
   <chr>                      
 1 Prairie_Potholes1          
 2 Prairie_Potholes2          
 3 Prairie_Potholes3          
 4 Prairie_Potholes4          
 5 Prairie_Potholes5          
 6 Prairie_Potholes6          
 7 Prairie_Potholes7          
 8 Prairie_Potholes8          
 9 Prairie_Potholes9          
10 Boreal_Hardwood_Transition1
11 Boreal_Hardwood_Transition2
12 Boreal_Hardwood_Transition3
13 Boreal_Hardwood_Transition4
14 Boreal_Hardwood_Transition5
15 Boreal_Hardwood_Transition6
```

Answer (score 6):

Unique within repeats

```
make.unique(c("Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", 
              "Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", 
              "Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", 
              "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", 
              "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition"), sep = "")
 [1] "Prairie_Potholes"            "Prairie_Potholes1"           "Prairie_Potholes2"           "Prairie_Potholes3"           "Prairie_Potholes4"          
 [6] "Prairie_Potholes5"           "Prairie_Potholes6"           "Prairie_Potholes7"           "Prairie_Potholes8"           "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition" 
[11] "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition1" "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition2" "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition3" "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition4" "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition5"
```

add a suffix to every row

```
x <- c("Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", 
  "Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", 
  "Prairie_Potholes", "Prairie_Potholes", "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", 
  "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", 
  "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition", "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition")

x <- paste0(x, 1:length(x))
x
 [1] "Prairie_Potholes1"            "Prairie_Potholes2"            "Prairie_Potholes3"            "Prairie_Potholes4"            "Prairie_Potholes5"           
 [6] "Prairie_Potholes6"            "Prairie_Potholes7"            "Prairie_Potholes8"            "Prairie_Potholes9"            "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition10"
[11] "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition11" "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition12" "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition13" "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition14" "Boreal_Hardwood_Transition15"
```